# How to put a body in get request in c# using Flurl?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, flurl

I'm trying to put a body in a get request using Flurl on c#.
I need to make a code that makes a get request as this curl :

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/my-index-000001/_search?from=40&size=20&pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "user.id": "kimchy"
    }
  }
}
'
```

Hope you can help me :)

Comment: Generally request body is ignored with a GET request, so its not surprising that there isn't an API to specifically append a body with a GET request.

Comment: Just use POST instead. Elasticsearch [supports](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html) this and it's [more correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/62600) in terms of what "should" be allowed by a RESTful API.